# extjs 4 - styling Ext.menu.Menu (floating)

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, menu

I'm trying to add some styling to a floating Ext.menu.Menu.  Specifically, I'm looking to create a menu that is shown below a component and has a little triangle shown on top similar to the css speech bubble found [here](http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-speech-bubble-generator.html)

I've tried styling the menu with css, but I can't get the triangle to show up with the generated CSS.  Any ideas on what I might need to override to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a class name with `componentCls`. Try something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    ... // some configs

    componentCls: 'floatingMenu',

    ... // other configs
});
```

Then you should be able to add your css styles with

```
.floatingMenu {
    // properties
}
```

Hope this helps!

Reference: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-cfg-componentCls